# Paired conjunction

Tags: correlative-conjunctions

An exercise contains five questions. 
I answered four questions and got them right, but the one I bring here I can't answer.
I tried all the possible solutions.

Here it is:

> Combine each pair of sentences into one new sentence use words in the box:
>
> - neither .... nor
> - either ..or
> - not only ... but also
>
> > **You can help your community by volunteering your time. If you are too busy, you can donate money.**

I tried :

1. You can help your community either by volunteering your time or by donating  money if you are too busy.
2. You can help your community either by volunteering your time or donate money if you are busy.
3. Unless you are too busy you can help your community either by volunteering or you can donate money.
4. You can either help your community by volunteering your time, or, if you are too busy, donate money.
5. Not only can you help your community by volunteering your time but you can also donate money if you are too busy.

All these I mentioned above I tried but when I click on <kbd>Finish</kbd>, the page says I got it wrong.

https://www.liveworksheets.com/worksheets/en/English_as_a_Second_Language_(ESL)/Conjunctions/Paired_Conjunctions_xl871fz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't get it right is because the test has it wrong. The answer it wants is

> you can help your community by either volunteer your time or donating money

It looks like it's not worried about capital letters or punctuation.

*Volunteer* is obviously incorrect: even the question has *volunteering.* The required answer has also lost the "if you are too busy" information.

I'd also prefer *either* to go before *by*. I think repeating *by* sounds better. However the other way isn't wrong.

> You can help your community either by volunteering your time, or — if you are too busy — by donating money.
>
> You can help your community by either volunteering your time or donating money if you are too busy to volunteer.

Computerised tests are generally poor, because there are always many ways of expressing something well, and most of them are better than what is actually expected. Especially here!

Comment: Thank you very much dear @Andrew Leach ..... I though the same ... The matter as mentioned or implied (( If you are too busy))  Of course in this case he can't volunteer by his time that he is busy. He can help his community by donating money instead, so linguistically the context is incorrect; therefore I suggest introducing the sentence by ( unless )  Unless you are too busy you can help your community either by volunteering or you can donate money = in this way he can offer helping completely without effort  ..... Thank you very much   Hope you well.